# Travis CI is showing Jekyll-generated website was built with 0 problems but changes not showing on website

Tags: jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages

I have a Jekyll + Travis CI generated website that is hosted on GitHubPages. Two years ago, I set up the site and haven't done much with it since, but it has been working fine since then.

Today I added two new blog posts (one in Spanish, one in English - I use [this](https://mrzool.cc/polyglot-jekyll/) plugin to switch between the two languages on this website) and some images.

They all show up on GitHub but not on the website, so it seems like the problem is with Travis when it is generating the static site.

But then when I go to the Travis website, it says that the build happened without problems.

Maybe it is just late in the day, but I have no idea how to trouble shoot this. Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: And your repository url is ?

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/teresacamachohull/teresacamachohull.github.io

Comment: You have an [authentication error](https://travis-ci.org/teresacamachohull/teresacamachohull.github.io/jobs/524177221#L587) when travis tries to push back to github. Check your Github pages token and your GH-PAGES token setup on travis.

Comment: thank you! that was exactly it. i really appreciate your help!